# How to compile and link generated files within msvc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My `msvc 2015` project has `foo.smth` file with custom build tool. That file is used to generate `foo1.c` and `foo2.c` source files, which will be located in `temp/intermediate` directory. Is there any way to compile and link such files using  `compiler and linker's` options from my project? Maybe there is way to implicitly add such files for compiler and linker?

UPD: at the moment, `foo.smth` file has `Item Type = Custom Build Tool`. Its command uses third party application to generate `.c` files

Comment: How is this custom build tool integrated at the moment? Are you just calling it from Build Events or a Custom Build Step?…

Comment: You could just add these files as items to the project. Doing so may, however, mess with the build dependency/incremental build logic unless the files are always going to be there and you properly set it up so that they are only overwritten when necessary.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, did you mean modification of `<ClCompile>` tag of msvc project? But it can lead to errors like `visual studio cannot open file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properies of your Custom Build Tool item, you should find the *Add Outputs to Item Type* property. If you set it to `ClCompile` (or select *C/C++ compiler* from the drop-down menu), that should cause the files listed in the *Outputs* property to be emitted as inputs for the C++ compiler. These should then automatically be compiled using your project's default C/C++ settings…